# Eclipse WizardPage for exporting a file

Tags: export, swt, wizard

I want to use the exportWizard extension point for an eclipse plugin. I am having some difficulties figuring out how a simple filedialog wizard page should look like.

```
public class ExportWizardPage extends WizardPage {

private FileDialog fileDialog=null;

protected ExportWizardPage(String pageName) {
    super(pageName);
}

@Override
public void createControl(Composite parent) {

    fileDialog = new FileDialog(parent.getShell(), SWT.SAVE);
    fileDialog.setFilterExtensions(new String[] { "*.bm" });
}
}
```

I am trying it currently like above and use a FileDialog for selecting the target file. Basically it works, the dialog is opened and I get the name of the file, but as soon the dialog closes I get an exception.

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:178)
```

I think I am using this Wizard/WizardPage mechanism wrongly, but I really could not found a simple example that showed me how something should look like.

Answer (score 3):

Your wizard page does not contain any controls. You should create one composite and then add all your controls to it (and NOT `parent` directly). Calling `setControl(..)` is also absolutely required. It should look something like this:

```
@Override
public void createControl(Composite parent) {
  Composite content = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

  // add all the controls to your wizard page here with 'content' as parent

  FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(parent.getShell(), SWT.SAVE);
  fileDialog.setFilterExtensions(new String[] { "*.bm" });

  setControl(content);
}
```